# Is it pssible to get AAD access_token from angular?

Tags: angular, azure, http, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get Azure Management Resource endpoint token from angular, thogh I know it is vulnarable doing in clinet side. For some strong reason I am searching to do it anyway.

As I can get access_token by running this command.

```
curl -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<client-id>&resource=<management-resource-endpoint>&client_secret=<application-secret>' \
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/token
```

I am trying to convert this command as http get request like it...

```
getAADToken() {
    const param = new HttpParams();
    param.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
    param.append('client_id', <client-id>);
    param.append('resource', '2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d');
    param.append('client_secret', <application-secret>);
    return this.http.get<any>("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/token", {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
      params:param
    });
  }
```

but getting CORS issue...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that since Azure AD doesn't allow you to use client credentials flow from a browser.
They would need to allow the cross-origin request, which you can't configure.

There are many security reasons why you cannot do this, the most obvious one that you mentioned being that the client secret is visible to anyone who visits the page.
Also anyone who can get that page's files can act on APIs *as the app*, so tracing who actually did something becomes quite difficult.

Typically when you need to do something as an app because the user can't do it,
you have the user authenticate in front-end, call a back-end API as them, the API authorizes the user, and then makes the app-only authenticated call to the target API.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this `AuthInterceptor` to the module

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

    intercept(request: Http`enter code here`Request<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return from(this.handleAccess(request, next));
    }
    private async handleAccess(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
        Promise<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const token = await this.getToken();
        let changedRequest = request;
        // HttpHeader object immutable - copy values
        const headerSettings: { [name: string]: string | string[]; } = {};

        for (const key of request.headers.keys()) {
            headerSettings[key] = request.headers.getAll(key);
        }
        if (token) {
            headerSettings['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
        }
        headerSettings['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        const newHeader = new HttpHeaders(headerSettings);

        changedRequest = request.clone({
            headers: newHeader
        });
        return next.handle(changedRequest).toPromise();
    }

    getToken = async () => {
        try {
            const pca = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
            const accounts = pca.getAllAccounts();
            const silentRequest = {
                scopes: [apiConfig.resourceScope],
                account: accounts[0],
            };
            const response = await pca.acquireTokenSilent(silentRequest);
            return response.accessToken;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };
}
```